# Python Sudoku Generator Code Not Responding: How to Fix the Unresponsiveness Issue

Tags: python, algorithm, user-interface, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am making a Sudoku generator code and it has 3 sizes 4x4 and 6x6 and 9x9 but when I run the 9x9 the code doesn't respond and in the task manager it is using 20% CPU usage and 0% Disk usage.

This is the full code

```
import numpy as np
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def generate_sudoku(size):
    grid = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=int)
    solve(grid)
    return grid

def solve(grid):
    size = len(grid)
    for row in range(size):
        for col in range(size):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                numbers = np.random.permutation(range(1, size + 1))
                for num in numbers:
                    if is_valid(grid, row, col, num):
                        grid[row][col] = num
                        if solve(grid):
                            return True
                        grid[row][col] = 0
                return False
    return True

def is_valid(grid, row, col, num):
    size = len(grid)
    # Check row
    if num in grid[row]:
        return False
    # Check column
    if num in grid[:, col]:
        return False
    # Check box
    box_size = int(size**0.5)
    box_row = row // box_size * box_size
    box_col = col // box_size * box_size
    box = grid[box_row:box_row+box_size, box_col:box_col+box_size]
    if num in box:
        return False
    return True

def remove_numbers(grid, num_clues):
    size = len(grid)
    cells = np.random.permutation(size * size)
    num_removed = 0
    for cell in cells:
        row = cell // size
        col = cell % size
        temp = grid[row][col]
        grid[row][col] = 0
        if not is_unique_solution(grid):
            grid[row][col] = temp
        else:
            num_removed += 1
            if num_removed >= size * size - num_clues:
                break

def is_unique_solution(grid):
    temp = grid.copy()
    return solve(temp)

def save_as_pdf(puzzles, solutions, puzzle_filename, solution_filename):
    # Save puzzles
    if puzzle_filename:
        c = canvas.Canvas(puzzle_filename, pagesize=A4)
        c.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

        num_puzzles = len(puzzles)
        num_per_page = 4  # Number of puzzles per page

        page_width, page_height = A4  # Get the page dimensions
        puzzle_width = 0.8 * page_width / (num_per_page // 2)
        puzzle_height = 0.8 * page_height / (num_per_page // 2)
        puzzle_margin = 0.05 * page_width  # Margin between puzzles

        total_puzzle_width = (puzzle_width + puzzle_margin) * (num_per_page // 2) - puzzle_margin
        puzzle_spacing = (page_width - total_puzzle_width) / 2

        for i in range(0, num_puzzles, num_per_page):
            c.showPage()
            for j in range(num_per_page):
                index = i + j
                if index < num_puzzles:
                    puzzle_x = puzzle_spacing + (j % (num_per_page // 2)) * (puzzle_width + puzzle_margin)
                    puzzle_y = page_height - (((j // (num_per_page // 2)) % 2) * (puzzle_height + puzzle_margin) + 0.1 * page_height)
                    draw_sudoku(c, puzzles[index], puzzle_x, puzzle_y)

        c.save()
        print("Puzzle PDF saved successfully!")

    # Save solutions
    if solution_filename:
        c = canvas.Canvas(solution_filename, pagesize=A4)
        c.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

        num_solutions = len(solutions)
        num_per_page = 4  # Number of solutions per page

        page_width, page_height = A4  # Get the page dimensions
        solution_width = 0.8 * page_width / (num_per_page // 2)
        solution_height = 0.8 * page_height / (num_per_page // 2)
        solution_margin = 0.05 * page_width  # Margin between solutions

        total_solution_width = (solution_width + solution_margin) * (num_per_page // 2) - solution_margin
        solution_spacing = (page_width - total_solution_width) / 2

        for i in range(0, num_solutions, num_per_page):
            c.showPage()
            for j in range(num_per_page):
                index = i + j
                if index < num_solutions:
                    solution_x = solution_spacing + (j % (num_per_page // 2)) * (solution_width + solution_margin)
                    solution_y = page_height - (((j // (num_per_page // 2)) % 2) * (solution_height + solution_margin) + 0.1 * page_height)
                    draw_sudoku(c, solutions[index], solution_x, solution_y)

        c.save()
        print("Solution PDF saved successfully!")


def draw_sudoku(canvas, grid, x, y):
    cell_width = 1.4224 * cm  # Cell width in inches
    cell_height = 1.4224 * cm  # Cell height in inches
    font_size = 0.5 * cm  # Decrease font size for 6x6 Sudoku

    size = len(grid)
    box_width = int(size**0.5)  # Number of cells in a row of the rectangular box
    box_height = int(size**0.5)  # Number of cells in a column of the rectangular box

    for i in range(size + 1):
        canvas.setLineWidth(0.1)  # Set line width to a smaller value for all lines
        canvas.line(x, y - i * cell_height, x + size * cell_width, y - i * cell_height)  # horizontal lines

        if i == 0 or i == size:  # Bold the outermost upper border and the outermost lower border
            canvas.setLineWidth(1)  # Set line width to a larger value for the outer borders
            canvas.line(x, y - i * cell_height, x + size * cell_width, y - i * cell_height)  # horizontal line

        if i % box_height == 0 and i > 0 and size > 4:
            canvas.setLineWidth(1)  # Set line width to a larger value for the rectangles
            canvas.line(x, y - i * cell_height, x + size * cell_width, y - i * cell_height)  # horizontal line

    for j in range(size + 1):
        canvas.setLineWidth(0.1)  # Set line width to a smaller value for all lines
        canvas.line(x + j * cell_width, y, x + j * cell_width, y - size * cell_height)  # vertical lines

        if j == 0 or j == size:  # Bold the outermost left border and the outermost right border
            canvas.setLineWidth(1)  # Set line width to a larger value for the outer borders
            canvas.line(x + j * cell_width, y, x + j * cell_width, y - size * cell_height)  # vertical line

        if j % box_width == 0 and j > 0 and size > 4:
            canvas.setLineWidth(1)  # Set line width to a larger value for the rectangles
            canvas.line(x + j * cell_width, y, x + j * cell_width, y - size * cell_height)  # vertical line

    canvas.setLineWidth(0.1)  # Set line width to a larger value for outer borders
    canvas.rect(x, y - size * cell_height, size * cell_width, size * cell_height)  # Draw the outer border

    # Draw text outside the table
    canvas.setFontSize(14)
    canvas.drawString(x, y + 0.3 * cm, "Sudoku")  # Example text

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            cell_value = str(grid[i][j])
            if cell_value != '0':
                canvas.setFontSize(font_size)
                text_width = canvas.stringWidth(cell_value, fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=font_size)
                cell_x = x + j * cell_width + (cell_width - text_width) / 2
                cell_y = y - i * cell_height - (cell_height - font_size) / 2
                canvas.drawString(cell_x, cell_y, cell_value)


def generate_sudoku_set(size, num_puzzles):
    puzzles = []
    solutions = []

    for _ in range(num_puzzles):
        puzzle = generate_sudoku(size)
        solution = puzzle.copy()
        remove_numbers(puzzle, get_num_clues(size))  # Adjust the number of clues as per your preference
        puzzles.append(puzzle)
        solutions.append(solution)

    puzzle_filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".pdf")
    solution_filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".pdf")

    save_as_pdf(puzzles, solutions, puzzle_filename, solution_filename)

def get_num_clues(size):
    if size == 4:
        return 8
    elif size == 6:
        return 12  # Decrease the number of clues for 6x6 Sudoku
    elif size == 9:
        return 22  # Decrease the number of clues for 9x9 Sudoku
    else:
        return 0

root = Tk()
root.title("Sudoku Generator")
root.geometry("300x200")

size_label = Label(root, text="Select Sudoku Size:")
size_label.pack(pady=10)

size_var = IntVar()
size_var.set(4)

radio_4x4 = Radiobutton(root, text="4x4", variable=size_var, value=4)
radio_4x4.pack()

radio_6x6 = Radiobutton(root, text="6x6", variable=size_var, value=6)
radio_6x6.pack()

radio_9x9 = Radiobutton(root, text="9x9", variable=size_var, value=9)
radio_9x9.pack()

num_puzzles_label = Label(root, text="Number of Puzzles:")
num_puzzles_label.pack(pady=10)

num_puzzles_entry = Entry(root)
num_puzzles_entry.pack()

generate_btn = Button(root, text="Generate Sudoku Set", command=lambda: generate_sudoku_set(size_var.get(), int(num_puzzles_entry.get())))
generate_btn.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me I have been working on this project for so much time
Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help

Comment: Is it just taking a long time to run with a 9x9 square? Put some simple print statements in your code to monitor progress.

Comment: Please tell us what your debugging session revealed... what is the bottle neck? Is it the pdf generation? If not, why does your question have the pdf code at all? Is it the solver? Please show your efforts to debug this.

Comment: So I just used another remove numbers function because this one is so much intensive def remove_numbers(grid, num_clues):
    size = len(grid)
    indices = np.random.choice(range(size*size), size*size - num_clues, replace=False)
    for index in indices:
        row = index // size
        col = index % size
        grid[row][col] = 0